# Get button text from event handler in F#

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

How can i get the clicked button text in buttonClick event handler?

```
let buttonClick args = 
  let rnd = new Random()
  //MessageBox.Show(button.Text)
  let r, g, b = rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256)
  form.BackColor <- Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)

for x = 0 to 3 do
  for y = 0 to 3 do
    let button = new Game15Button(new Point(x, y))
    button.Size <- new Size(50, 50)
    button.Click.Add(buttonClick)
    form.Controls.Add(button)
```

Comment: You seem to be a C# dev.  A general hint is that everything works exactly the same way in C# and F#

Comment: @JohnPalmer  I can use the sender argument in C#, var button = (Button)sender; but in F# there is only one EventArgs argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `buttonClick` function to getting 2 arguments, where the added one will be button's text the caller knows. But now you can't assign this function as the eventhandler for the button click because that has to only get 1 parameter. One solution is to use a lambda function with 1 argument that calls your `buttonClick` function with the buttons text and passes its argument as the second argument.

Changer your eventhandler to

```
let buttonClick text args = 
  let rnd = new Random()
  MessageBox.Show(text)
  let r, g, b = rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256)
  form.BackColor <- Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)
```

and the line where you assign the handler to the click to

```
button.Click.Add(fun args -> buttonClick button.Text args)
```